# Discovery Service Bad Digest

Tags: discovery-service

We have installed some of the microservices of SDL Web 8.5. Looking at the logs of the discovery service, after starting the server I'm getting an ERROR DefaultOAuthToken - Digest is wrong.

We think that it seems something related to a password but we have tried the passwords encrypted and without encryption and the same trace is always there.

I have this configuration in the cd_storage_conf.xml (by default):

http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc}" TokenServiceUrl="${tokenurl:-http://localhost:8082/token.svc}">
        
        
            http://localhost:8082/token.svc}"/>

The user is specified by default in the cd_ambient_conf.xml

Can you help us or do you know what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be this  issue related to Authentication Server SharedSecret defined in the cd_ambient_conf.xml should be the same SharedSecret for other services of  cd_ambient_conf.xml and same for DigestKey in case if you enabled to use Header and cookie validation options

Comment: Refer to this https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tridion-2011-sp1-hr1-odata-access-token/149#149